# Compile minimal test shared library using clang

Tags: c, makefile, clang, shared-libraries, freebsd

I am trying to compile a minimal test shared library in FreeBSD using:

```
FreeBSD clang version 6.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_601/final 335540) (based on LLVM 6.0.1)
Target: x86_64-unknown-freebsd12.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

**test.c**

```c
#include "test.h"

int SampleFunction(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

**test.h**

```c
#ifndef TESTLIB_H
#define TESTLIB_H

extern int SampleFunction(int a, int b);

#endif
```

**Makefile**

```
# Makefile TESTLIB

TEST_OBJS = test.o
TEST_HEADERS = test.h
TEST_LIB = test.so

CC = cc

testlib:    $(TEST_OBJS)
        $(CC) -fpic -o $(TEST_LIB) $(TEST_OBJS)

# Rebuilt if this Makefile or header changes
$(TEST_OBJS):   Makefile $(TEST_HEADERS)
```

Output:

```
$ make testlib
cc  -O2 -pipe -c test.c -o test.o
cc -fpic -o test.so test.o
/usr/bin/ld: error: undefined symbol: main
>>> referenced by crt1.c:76 (/usr/src/lib/csu/amd64/crt1.c:76)
>>>               /usr/lib/crt1.o:(_start)
cc: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/home/user/testlib
```

Comment: add `-shared` to linker: `cc -fpic -shared -o test.so test.o`

Answer (score 2):

As well as adding `-shared` to the linker stage (as mentioned by Oo.oO), you probably also want to compile with the `-fPIC` flag as well. So if you are using the makefile implicit rules for the compiling (looks like you are) then you will probably want to add that flag to `CFLAGS`. I don't think you need it for the linking stage:

```
# Makefile TESTLIB

TEST_OBJS = test.o
TEST_HEADERS = test.h
TEST_LIB = test.so

CFLAGS += -fPIC
CC = cc

testlib:    $(TEST_OBJS)
        $(CC) -shared -o $(TEST_LIB) $(TEST_OBJS)

# Rebuilt if this Makefile or header changes
$(TEST_OBJS):   Makefile $(TEST_HEADERS)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the OS-provided `bsd.lib.mk` for such building libraries. The following should do the right thing -- whatever it may be:

```
SHLIB_NAME= testlib
SRCS= test.c

.include <bsd.lib.mk>
```

(For building executables there is `bsd.prog.mk`, BTW.)